# Unruh effect on rotating galaxies?

Tags: galaxy-rotation-curve, unruh-effect

According to the Unruh effect, an accelerating observer will experience a thermal bath. This is equivalent to Hawking radiation.

If we applied this to a spinning galaxy, I wonder if this thermal bath would affect the rotation curve of a galaxy by the matter interacting with the thermal bath.

Since a star travelling in empty space in a straight line with no acceleration would have no Unruh effect, but a star in the arm of a galaxy would be accelerating.

It would seem that it should have some affect and the affect should depend on the constitution of the matter involved.

Is there a simple argument to say whether the Unruh effect would change the rotation curve of a galaxy (and by how much?). I imagine the effect would be pretty small. But then again, a galaxy does have a lot of matter in it.

From the stars perspective not only is it gravitated by the galaxy but perhaps also is affected (gravitionally?) by the thermal bath which would appear to have it's own energy.

Comment: It seems somebody thought Unruh could replace dark matter  https://arxiv.org/abs/1207.7007  also later https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10509-017-3128-6

Comment: @anna Yes, but this "quantised inertia" is said to be pseudoscience on Wikipedia. So I don't know what to think of it.

Comment: well, it shows that unruh has a collective effect, the calculation from somebody else show different predictions according to the critics, but it shows an effect of Unruh  can be calculated.

Comment: looking at "quantized inertia" with google it shows it is still researched, but anyway it answers your title question, whether an effect exists. ( not whether quantized inertia is valid)

Comment: Is it really correct that a star in the arm of the galaxy experiences an Unruh effect? Because it is not accelerated but in free fall, right? The acceleration you would classically assign to it via the centripetal force is not the acceleration meant in the Unruh effect. So the only Unruh effect should be due to the non-zero curvature of the spacetime it is located on.  But is there even an Unruh effect for a free falling observer on curved spacetime?

Comment: @Cream  I do not see that acceleration should be differently defined in electromagnetism and gravity: charged traks in a circle have syncrotorn radiation as expected from the radial dp/dt

Comment: @annav I know the Unruh effect only for accelerated observers, not for free falling ones. Acceleration in GR is different. From the viewpoint of GR, the star is not "accelerated" but follows the geodesic. Also, I do not see how the analogy to electromagnetism applies, the Unruh effect is not an equivalent of synchrotron radiation (for example: An accelerated observer moving in a straight line experiences the Unruh effect, but an accelerated electron does not emit synchrotron radiation).

Comment: @Cream (an accelerated electron does emit radiation, called bremstrahlung, but it is just an analogous phenomenon) . Using the geodesic language you cannot be talking of acceleration. One can show mathematically that the GR mathematical framework, in flat spaces and smaller masses reduces to Newtonian gravity mathematics, acceleration and all.